# Troubleshooting StyleGAN3: training model collapse and warnings encountered during evaluation despite using --workers=2 flag

Tags: deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network, stylegan

I am attempting to train [StyleGAN3](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan3) on Google Cloud using the following setup:

```
2vCPU
13GB of RAM
Nvidia T4
PyTorch 1.13
CUDA 11.3
Python 3.10
```

My dataset consists of approximately 14,000 JPG images of dresses sketchs, which I converted to PNG format using Pillow Python script.

[dataset sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN2SJ.jpg)

```py
import os
from PIL import Image

def convert_images(input_folder, output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

    for filename in os.listdir(input_folder):
        if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
            # Open the image
            image_path = os.path.join(input_folder, filename)
            image = Image.open(image_path)

            # Convert to PNG format
            new_filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".png"
            output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, new_filename)
            image.save(output_path, "PNG")

            print(f"Converted {filename} to {new_filename}")

    print("Conversion completed.")
input_path = "/home/..../img"
output_path = "/home/..../converted_img"
convert_images(input_path, output_path)
```

I built the dataset using the following command:
 `python dataset_tool.py --source /home/..../converted_img --dest /home/..../dataset.zip --resolution=256x256`

The training process starts with the following command:
 `python train.py --data=/home/..../dataset.zip --outdir=/home/..../training-runs --cfg=stylegan3-t --gpus=1 --batch=32 --gamma=2 --batch-gpu=16 --snap=10 --mirror=1 --workers=2`

Initially, everything seems to work fine, but the training process stops earlier than expected, and the evaluation phase begins. Unfortunately, I have been stuck on the evaluation phase for about an hour probably due to a warning message.

[waring message displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQaWx.png)

I used --workers=1 but metrics still seems freeze so I have to disable them.

Additionally, I would like to share the training result I obtained.

[collapsed generated fake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9eTi.png)

The model is cleary collapsed.

Could you please provide guidance on how to best present the training result for further analysis and troubleshooting?

Thank you for your assistance.